# How to remove this white highlight from html tags (vscode)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags, highlight

the white highlight on html tags by vscode looks ugly

[image]

Comment: can you pls sharer a snippet or screenshot of the code?

Comment: @Uzair He did...

Comment: its not like we can customize it, but you could simply use another theme from vs code and see for yourself if you like it, although it wont go away entirely as it indicates which block of code you are currently working in. I use __Andromeda__ theme and it reduces the highlight to a good extent

Comment: you can customize every color of the theme, just make the colors you don't like transparent or equal to the non-highlight version

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.json put:

Highlight matching brackets when one of them is selected.

> "editor.matchBrackets": false,

That will stop the behaviour you see, but will do it for all supported languages (so also javascript for example). You can change that setting for only html by :

```
"[html]": {
   "editor.matchBrackets": false
}
```

Comment: thank you to all who helped me with this 

Comment: Happy to Help! 

Answer (score 0):

It changed from a boolean to a string.

`"editor.matchBrackets":` options are now: "always", "near", or "never"